# How do access methods from one component in a different component in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, material-design

I have a `navigation` and a `drawer` class in my components (in different files). I want to be able to have a menu button in the `navigation` class which opens and closes the drawer. I have a `toggleStatus` method in the `drawer` class which changes the state of `drawerStatus` to open/closed. How do I access the `toggleStatus` method from within the `navigation` class? I am using material-design for all my components.

Comment: What kind of state management are you using? If you use redux, you could fire an action that hits the drawer reducer. If the drawer is a child of the navigation, you could access the method by setting a `ref` on the drawer, and using the local reference to trigger changes

Comment: In the simplest case, your navigation component could pass an event/callback up, and then the parent component can change a boolean prop on the `drawer` component to open or close it. See [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from the docs. Having components call each others' methods is rarely a good fit for the React model (although there's some cases where you could make a case for it).

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks, this makes sense. If components shouldn't be calling each others' methods, how would you recommend I achieve this? Is it worth combining the drawer and navigation into one component/class?

Comment: @Ryan: See sandddyyyy's answer - that shows pretty much exactly what I was describing :)

Comment: @Ryan you might give Redux a try, it make our lives - React devs - easier. Managing the whole application state in only one place as a single source of truth. Just brilliant!

Comment: @JoeClay yeah! Lifting State Up - totally agree with you. However, I think using Redux might be worth considering.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú: Redux is definitely worth considering here too :) I'm just wary of recommending people go down that route before they have a good understanding of the React model - I think it's very easy to over-complicate things if you bring in Redux too early. For a big app, state management libraries are great, but for small demos your life will probably be a lot easier just passing props up and down!

Comment: Yep. If it includes routing, local states might not do the exact job since once they're unmounted, the state resets. Dispatching action and using reducers to mutate state with state management tools like Redux could be the best approach for this.

Comment: @sandddyyyy, JoeClay yeah! In Ryan's case, I saw that this is a serious application with the uses of material-design for the Navigation, Drawer and probably more. React-Router might be included in that Ryan's project as well.  I think Redux is what Ryan actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `navigation` and `drawer` components are children of a parent component, declare a method that updates `drawerStatus` and pass it as prop to `navigation` and add state to that parent component and pass it as prop to `drawer`. It's something like this:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = { isDrawerOpen: false };
  }

  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.setState({ isDrawerOpen: !this.state.isDrawerOpen });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavigationComponent toggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer} />
        <DrawerComponent drawerStatus={this.props.isDrawerOpen} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as a props.

I.E.
      I have this Heirarchy :

```
<Foo>
<Bar/>
</Foo>
```

and inside foo , you have a function called toggle.

```
toggle(){
    console.log('triggered')
}
```

You can pass in toggle to Bar as props like this :

```
<Bar
    toggleInBar={this.toggle.bind(this)}
/>
```

and inside bar component , you can use the toggleInBar as props.

```
this.props.toggleInBar
```

will trigger the logging :)

P.S. 
I Intentionally did a different name to differentiate the functions easier :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it this way:
1-  you button class might look like so :

```
import React from 'react'; // import react module
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="button"
      onClick={props.handleClick}
      value={props.label}
    />
  );
}

// describe our expected props types
Button.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  handleClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

// export our button component.
export default Button;
```

You parent component could be something like so:

```
import React from 'react'; // import react module
import Button from './button'; // Import our button component from this directory
// create a class which extends react component
class Frame extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  // our method to handle all click events from our buttons
  handleClick(event){
    const value = event.target.value; // get the value from the target element (button)
    switch (value) {
      case '1': {
         //handler for tia button with lable "1"
        break;
      }
      default: {
        // your default implementation 
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Render function to creat component to be rendered on the DOM.
  // This method must return a single parent element as you can see here. 
  // The component is wrapped around () to make it a single expression.
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="frame">
          <Button className='btn-primary' label={'1'} handleClick={this.handleClick} type='input' />
    );
  }
}

// export our frame component. To be used in our client/index.js file
export default Frame;
```